# Error code -50 when copying file to external drive

Tags: macos

I have a Western Digital MyBook external hard drive. It generally works fine, but often when I try to copy a file to the drive, I get "The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -50). If I try using the `cp` command in the terminal instead, I get "Invalid argument". If I then try to eject the drive and remount, everything works fine.

It seems that these hard drives spin down after about 10 minutes of inactivity. That doesn't really bother me, and I'm not positive this is the issue, as I can browse around the drive fine once it spins up again, but I still get the copy error.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Disk format is Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Example of `cp` command I used: `cp /Users/Ben/Desktop/test.txt /Volumes/Media`

Comment: which data system are you using ? FAT 32 or NTSFS?

Comment: What's the `cp` command you're using?  It tough to diagnose an invalid argument when we can't see the actual arguments.

Comment: @FabianGr thanks for your input, I've updated the question to answer your query

Comment: @Allan just the straight `cp` command, updated the question to provide an example

Comment: In terms of the file system a `-50` error refers to a `paramErr: Error in user parameter list`. There are a number of scenarios that can trigger this error (e.g. if filenames use certain characters not compatible with the file system of the disk you're copying to). Since your external drive is formatted with Mac OS Extended (Journaled), this isn't going to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, without further details it's going to be hard to definitively diagnose this. Have you noticed any patterns (e.g. it's only triggered when copying video files, it only happens when copying folders, etc)? Is it repeatable (i.e. if you get the error when copying a certain file, do you get the error again the next time you try copying the same file (even after a restart)? Also, what happens if you disable the option to *Put hard disks to sleep when possible* (in System Preferences > Energy Saver)? Does the error occur in Safe Mode? Finally, what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @Monomeeth once the error starts occurring, it happens with all files & folders. I can still browse the drive, but copying anything fails every time, until I force eject the drive and mount it again. "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" is disabled, but the WD drives have their own controller that spins the drive down after 10 mins. I suspect it's somehow related to this. Copy works fine after restart, I guess as the drive is remounted. Running macOS 10.12.2 - I can try upgrading to High Sierra if you feel it's worth trying.

Comment: Have you noticed this issue when using the drive with any other computer? Or do you only use it with this Mac? Have you also tested the drive on another USB port? (I assume also it's connected directly to your Mac?) Is this drive USB powered, or does it have its own power source? Also, what model of Mac are you using? It's probably worth at least updating macOS to 10.12.6, as it has a number of improvements etc over 10.12.2 anyway and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've had a few problems with processes bogging down or quitting in High Sierra. Does the copy complete successfully immediately after a restart?

Comment: You could try [turning off app nap globally](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/13/disable-app-nap-mac-os-x/)

Comment: @Monomeeth I haven’t had the problem once since updating to 10.13.6, so I’m reasonably hopeful it’s fixed now. Either way you’ve given a lot of useful suggestions, so if you want to post an answer I’m happy to send the bounty your way.